# Error in Dispatch Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I'm studying event on Symfony. 
I Want send an email each time a new user registers

I have created these class

```
UserEvent.php
    <?php
    namespace Acme\UserBundle\Event;


    final class UserEvents {

        const NEW_USER='new.user';


    }
```

newUserEvent.php

```
<?php

/**
 * EVENT DISPATCHER
 */
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Event;

use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;


class NewUserEvent {

    protected $user;

    public function __construct (User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser () {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

newUserListener.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Event;


class NewUserListener {

    public function sendEmailToUsers(NewUserEvent $event)
    {
        // ... send email to users
    }
}
```

in my controller

```
/**
     * @Route("/test",name="test")
     */
    public function testEvento(){

        $em = $this->getEm();

        $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

        // attach listener
        $listner = new NewUserListener();
        $dispatcher->addListener(UserEvents::NEW_USER,array($listner,'sendEmailToUsers'));

        $user = $em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('username' => 'alex')); //mock
        $event = new NewUserEvent($user);

        $dispatcher->dispatch(UserEvents::NEW_USER,$event);



        return new Response('hi');
    }
```

But I get this Error

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher::dispatch() must be
>   an instance of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event

I don't understand my mistake

Comment: Try changing `class NewUserEvent {` to `class NewUserEvent extends Event {`

Comment: Symfony's [**EventDispatcher::dispatch()**](https://github.com/symfony/EventDispatcher/blob/v2.6.1/EventDispatcherInterface.php#L38) needs an instance of its own [**Event**](https://github.com/symfony/EventDispatcher/blob/v2.6.1/Event.php) class. Therefore, if you want to use it, your custom event must extends this last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Read this.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html)**

1. `class NewUserEvent` must extend `Event` class (`Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event`)
2. access to `event_dispatcher` service in controller - `$this->get('event_dispatcher')`